# I'm getting a NoReverseMatch error with my delete view

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a NoReverseMatch error with my delete view. I think it is with my success url in my views.py but I don't know what to do I even put a kwargs with a pk key in the reverse lazy but still won't work.

Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.urls import reverse_lazy 
from django.contrib import messages
from . import forms
from . import models
# Create your views here.

class AnnouncementListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = models.Announcement

class AnnouncementDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView ):
    model = models.Announcement

class AnnouncementUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.UpdateView):
    model = models.Announcement
    form_class = forms.AnnouncementForm

class AnnouncementCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView ):
    model = models.Announcement
    form_class = forms.AnnouncementForm

class AnnouncementDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DeleteView ):
    model = models.Announcement
    success_url = reverse_lazy('announcement:single')

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(self.request, "Post Deleted")
        return super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

announcement_confirm_delete.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'announcement:destroy' announcement.pk %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <input class='btn btn-danger' type="submit" value="Delete" />
            <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-light btn-large">Cancel</a>

          </div>
    </form>
</div>
    
{% endblock  %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm getting a NoReverseMatch error when I go into the DetailView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765004/im-getting-a-noreversematch-error-when-i-go-into-the-detailview)

Answer (score 0):

Your succes ulr of `AnnouncementDeleteView`  must be changed, now it's:

> `success_url = reverse_lazy('announcement:single')`

I think it must be: `success_url = reverse_lazy('announcement:list')`

or add primary key: `reverse_lazy('announcement:single', kwargs={'pk': desired_id})`

Answer (score 0):

As the screenshot on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767016/im-getting-a-noreversematch-error-in-my-home-page/65767365?noredirect=1#comment116280544_65767365) shows, `announcement:single` requires a `pk` argument, so you'd need to use a function to support that in a `success_url`.

Django's generic views have a [`get_success_url`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/#get_success_url);

```py
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse_lazy('announcement:single', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})
```

However that's on a delete view, so on success you can't go to a view detailing the object you've just deleted, so it'd make more sense to go to the list view on deletion success.